# php notice (trying to get property of non-object) error

Tags: php

So, I have following php for wp:

```
 $usersNames = array();
 foreach ($userIDs as $userId) {
            $userInfo = get_userdata($userId);
            $usersNames[] = $userInfo->display_name; //this one                                     
        }
```

I am getting an error for `$usersNames`.

```
"PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /functions.php on line"
```

What is going on?

Any suggestions?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

So, for `$userIDs`, I have an array of user ids. Then I am trying to get user display name etc for individual ids.

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($userInfo);`?

Comment: Please add function `get_userdata` to your question so that we can see, which data is returned by that function.

Comment: It is `wp` function. Here is the `get_userdata` codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata

Comment: I edited the code for the simplicity

Comment: `If the user does not exist, the function returns false.`  So obvioulsy some users don't exist.

Comment: Is that what it means? so there is no info and the function is trying to get that info?

Comment: It means that as there is no user with some id - then function returns `false`.

Comment: Echo your ids and see which of them exist in db.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function `get_userdata()` will return [`False on failure, WP_User object on success.`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata#Return_Values)

And error `Trying to get property of non-object` means that this function has returned `false`.

Simply check if `$userInfo` is not empty

```
$userInfo = get_userdata($userId);

if (!empty($userInfo)) {
    $usersNames[] = $userInfo->display_name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved the issue. ! Appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

you need judge whether $userInfo return the right obj

```js
 $usersNames = array();
 foreach ($userIDs as $userId) {
            $userInfo = get_userdata($userId);
            $usersNames[] = isset($userInfo->display_name)?$userInfo->display_name:''; //this one                                     
        }
```

Comment: It will create empty entry. I think it's better to not include empty values.